# Dash - multi-user with multiple possible dashboards

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building a multi user Dash application where based on certain credentials in a database, the User will only be able to see a certain dashboard once they have been verified. Like a manager could be able to see all there employee data in a dashboard but an employee would be only able to see there data.

I am trying to be able to load a python file that will be able to contain the entire layout, functions, and callbacks for a dash application so that I can have it all in one place. However, I have not been able to figure out how to do so. Is this possible in any manner?

```
def create_dashboard(server):

    """Create a Plotly Dash dashboard embedded within Flask"""
    dash_app = dash.Dash(server=server,
                        routes_pathname_prefix='/dashapp/',
                        external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CERULEAN],
    )
        

    dash_app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                html.H1(id="my-header", className="text-center"),
            ], className="col-md-12")
        ], className="row"),            
        html.A('Login', id="login-link", href="/login"),
        html.Div(id="my-div", className="text-center"),
        html.Button(id='submit-button-state', n_clicks=1, children='Submit',
        style={'display': 'none'}),
    ])
    
    
    @dash_app.callback(
        [Output(component_id='my-header', component_property='children'),
        Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
        Output(component_id='login-link', component_property='style')],
        [Input(component_id='submit-button-state', component_property='n_clicks')]
    )
    
    def get_user_name(n_clicks):
        """
        The dashboard only loads if a user is authenticated
        """
        if routes.get_user().is_authenticated:
            welcome_msg = "Welcome back, " + routes.get_user().username
            user_data = load_data()
            link_style = {'display':'none'}
            return welcome_msg, user_data, link_style
        return "Your Princess is in another castle", ''


    def load_data():
        """
        The user's data is pulled from a database. As the user has already been
        authenticated, the 'current_user' from 'flask_login' is used within a database
        query, ensuring that the correct user's data is loaded. This is the key to
        having multiple user authentication with dedicated views for each user.
        """
        u = routes.get_user()
        data = u.data_for_user.all()
        if data.x1 == some data:
            dash_app = dashboard.py # some dashboard py file that needs to be loaded for the user

        return dash_app
    
    return dash_app.server
```